# Importing text files using a loop

Tags: python-2.7

I want to import text files  using a loop instead of importing them one by one.

I have 9 text files labelled clump0.txt - clump9.txt and after importing them I have to assign a variable.

```
ymport.textClumps('/tmp/clump1.txt')
#c0 = getClumpInfo()
c0 = pack.SpherePack()
c0.fromSimulation()
O.resetThisScene()

ymport.textClumps('/tmp/clump1.txt')
#c1 = getClumpInfo()
c1 = pack.SpherePack()
c1.fromSimulation()
O.resetThisScene()

ymport.textClumps('/tmp/clump2.txt')
#c1 = getClumpInfo()
c2 = pack.SpherePack()
c2.fromSimulation()
O.resetThisScene()

ymport.textClumps('/tmp/clump3.txt')
#c1 = getClumpInfo()
c3 = pack.SpherePack()
c3.fromSimulation()
O.resetThisScene()
...
```

Later I am using c0-c9 in this:

```
test = sp.makeClumpCloud(minCorner, maxCorner, [c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9], periodic=True, num = -1)
```

I already tried:

```
# load clumps
arr = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9]
for i in range (0, 9):
    ymport.textClumps("/tmp/clump{}.txt".format(i))
    arr[i] =pack.SpherePack()
    arr[i].fromSimulation()
    O.resetThisScene()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it doing

## load clumps

arr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

```
for i in range (0, 9):
    ymport.textClumps(str(os.getcwd()) + "/tmp/clump{}.txt".format(i))
    arr[i] = pack.SpherePack()
    arr[i].fromSimulation()
    O.resetThisScene()
```

I just had to assign a placeholder into the array :) Thanks